# Are non-computable and undecidable the same?

Tags: logic, terminology, computability, decidability

What is the difference between non-computable and undecidable if any?

Comment: One refers to a function, the other, to a proposition.

Comment: What the deuce is going on, closing this as "missing context"? That's our codespeak for "this looks like a homework question that you're making no effort on", but there is no way this can be a homework problem. Which kind of "thoughts" and "attempts" do the close-voters imagine the OP could conceivably provide here?

Comment: @Henning, I take your point, but isn't this a very odd question? A little like, what is the difference between round and blue? or between continuous and true?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That's stretching it a little far, given that _one_ of the meanings of "decidable" is very close to "computable", to the extent that both words are used (usually by different authors, to be sure) about the _same_ class of subsets of $\mathbb N$. There are other meanings where everyone agree that only one of the words is appropriate, and an answer would explain that, too.

Comment: @Henning, OK, the question has been re-opened. I think you're in a better position to post an answer than I am, maybe you'd like to.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of computability theory, there is no difference between a non-computable set and an undecidable set.

The term "undecidable" is also used in logic to refer to a statement that is not provable or disprovable from a particular theory. For example, the continuum hypothesis is undecidable from the axioms of ZF set theory.  This is distinct from the meaning of "undecidable" in computability theory.

Answer (score -1):

A great connection between logic and computation is the Curry–Howard correspondence, that see propositions as types and elements as proofs of the propositions.

In this context, proving something is equivalent to building a program. One must start from some main building blocks (the standard libraries) to derive new elements.

On the other side, computation means that there is a finite algorithm that leads to a result. Using the correspondence, this is equivalent to say that a function/element returns something, i.e. that the element is not of type 0 (the empty type). Therefore, something non-computable must be and element of type 0.

If we are working on a consistent system (where we cannot derive an element of type 0) then undecidable statements are equivalent to non-computable, because by definition both cannot be derived.

The subtle part is that computation as we know it depends on the axioms (standard library). If the axioms are all computable we **may** end up building only computable proofs, but if we assume some axiom that performs some sort of non-computable task e.g. a super task, then the proofs would be computable in the sense of the axioms but non-computable in the sense that requires an infinite number of steps.